# Filtering an Object Array with another Array of a different type

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

I have read everything I can and can't seem to figure this out. I have an ItemManager class that creates an array of [Item].  I need to be able to filter the [ItemManager.Items] array with another array [Category.name].  Specifically, I want to filter all of the Array elements in ItemManager.Items that contain the Array elements in Category.name.  Any help is appreciated.

```
class Item: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var category: String?
    var price: Int?

    init(name: String, category: String, price: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.price = price
    }
}

class ItemManager: NSObject {
    static var items = [Item]()

    class func addItem(name: String, category: String, price: Int) {
        let i = Item(name: name, category: category, price: price)
        return items.append(i)
    }
}

struct Category {
    var name: [String]

    subscript(index: Int) -> String {
    return name[index]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Give the following a try

**1. Add items to the list:**

```
ItemManager.addItem(name: "Basketball", category: "Sports", price: 20)
ItemManager.addItem(name: "Football", category: "Sports", price: 15)
ItemManager.addItem(name: "Flashlight", category: "Outdoors", price: 35)
ItemManager.addItem(name: "Code Complete", category: "Books", price: 70)
ItemManager.addItem(name: "Code Complete 2nd Edition", category: "Books", price: 72)
```

**2. Create an array of categories that will be used to filter the `ItemManager.list`:**

```
let categoriesToFilterBy = ["Sports", "Outdoors"]
```

**3. Filter the `ItemManager.list` using the `filter` method:**

```
var filteredList = ItemManager.items.filter {
    if let category = $0.category {
        return categoriesToFilterBy.contains(category)
    }
    return false
}
```

**4. Print the results:**

```
for item in filteredList {
    if let name = item.name, let category = item.category, let price = item.price {
        print("Item Name: \(name), Category: \(category), Price: \(price)")
    }
}
```

**5. Results (Note: Only categories that were equal to "Sports" and "Outdoors" were printed):**

```
Item Name: Basketball, Category: Sports, Price: 20
Item Name: Football, Category: Sports, Price: 15
Item Name: Flashlight, Category: Outdoors, Price: 35
```

---

The `filter` method on an array takes a closure that is expected to return `true` if the element should be included in the array that is returned or `false` if the element should not be part of the array that is returned.

You can read more about the filter method here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688383-filter

Comment: Works like a charm!  I wasn't iterating the resultant array from the filter.  Thanks.